# can't access fetched Objects from CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am trying to access fetched Objects from `NSFetchedResultsController`, but everytime I try to access, it gives an error saying

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'cannot access fetched objects before -performFetch:'

Following is my code to access fetched objects

```
do {
    try self.fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
} catch {
    print("An error occured when fetching results")
}

//  First layout if needed
self.tableView.reloadData()

if let orderUUID = notification.object as? String,
    let orders = self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects as? [CustomObject],
    let thisOrder = orders.filter({ $0.order!.uuid! == orderUUID }).first,
    let indexPath = self.fetchedResultsController.indexPath(forObject: thisOrder) {
        Log.verbose?.message("Order Detail opening after notification \(orderUUID) at Index \(indexPath)")
}
```

Comment: Which line of the code makes the error?

Comment: Did your `print` message appear? If your code has an error in `performFetch`, it still goes on and tries to use `fetchedObjects`.